# Python - How to modify dictionary values - increment or decrement by an integer value

Tags: python, dictionary

Have a problem trying to add or subtract an integer value from all values in a dictionary and returning the modified dictionary. Below is my Python code:

```
def increment(dictionary):
    for entry in dictionary:
        dictionary[entry] += 1 ## or -= 1

    return dictionary
```

Got this error code but don't know how to overcome it:
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +=: 'dict' and 'int'

Can someone tell me what I'm overlooking?

-Edited-

Here's an example of the case of dictionary:
{'x':{'y':{'z':15}}}

I'd like to increase 15 to 16.

Comment: It sounds like `dictionary[entry]` was of type `dict`. Can you provide some more context of how `dictionary` is populated?

Comment: Please provide what's inside of your dictionary. The error shows that your dict values are not integer, but another dict.

Comment: Show us the initialization of the `dictionary` object and the call to `increment(...)`.  This will help us help you get a fix.  Because the error itself is clearly stated in the the error message.

Comment: At least provide a dump of the dictionary

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution for a recursive incrementation:

```
def increment(dictionary):    
    for entry in dictionary:
        if type(dictionary[entry]) is dict:
            dictionary[entry] = increment(dictionary[entry])
        else:
            dictionary[entry] += 1

    return dictionary


d = {'x': {'y': {'z': 15}}}

print(increment(d))
```

prints `{'x': {'y': {'z': 16}}}`

Comment: Very elegant solution...+1

Comment: i see! I never thought about isolating and using recursion to tackle the case for if the entry in the dictionary is a dictionary itself. Thank you :)